# How to edit refactored icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am having trouble editing the icon widget I refactored within flutter. 
Here is my code:

```dart
class DetailsInput extends StatelessWidget {
      DetailsInput({
        this.label,
        this.keyboard,
        this.icon,
      });

      final String label;
      final TextInputType keyboard;
      final IconData icon;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: keyboard,
            cursorColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
              ),
              fillColor: Colors.black54,
              focusColor: Colors.black54,
              hintText: label,
              hoverColor: Colors.black54,
              hintStyle: kBasicLabelStyle,
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Here is the area where I have placed the code and am trying to modify its style:

```dart
DetailsInput(
    icon: Icons.contact_phone,
    keyboard: TextInputType.number,
),
```

I am trying to change the color of the icon above but am currently being preventing from doing so.

Comment: Can you show where do you try to change the icon color? How are you being prevented from doing so?

Comment: I have tried both within the refactored DetailsInput refactored area and within DetailsInput(
          icon: Icons.contact_phone,
          keyboard: TextInputType.number,
        ),

Comment: I think you do not use any `Icon` in the code you posted

Comment: Sorry, where should that be placed?

Comment: You need to add it to `InputDecoration` like so `icon: Icon(icon)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `InputDecoration`, add :

```dart
suffixIcon: const Icon(icon, color: Colors.red),
```